# Trying to connect my WinCSP to my host server and it gives me a timeout error

Tags: flask, python-3.8

I'm trying out Flask Framework and I created a free account on PythonAnywhere.com, I've been trying to connect my WinCSP to my domain and it keeps giving me a timeout error. If anybody has an idea on how to fix this, it would help me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Free accounts do not get SSH access, so you will not be able to connect WinSCP to a free account.